Defaulting to a different interpolation config if primary interpolation key is not found
I have a very complex hydra applications for fine-tuning LLMs. I have a data_preparation config group which is used both as a primary config group for offline data processing and within the trainer for processing data on the fly during inference. As such, the interpolation paths for some members of my config change between the two settings. I was wondering if it is possible to have omegaconf interpolate using an alternative key if the primary key is not found. I have tried something along the lines
  cache_path: ${oc.select:${data_path}/invocations_cache.json,${data_preparation.data_path}/invocations_cache.json}

which fails with an InterpolationKeyError because ${data_path} cannot be resolved and the resolution of the default is not attempted.
Is this possible at all?

This is not supported in the way you are asking for it.
oc.select is a wrapepr for OmegaConf.select(). It takes a key and a default value to use if the key is not present.
I see two options:

Make sure that the key is present, but make the default value an interpolation to the value you actually want to fallback to.

Implement your own custom resolver that does what you want.


I suggest that you go with option 1.
